# Задача по теории вероятности (биномиальное и геометрическое распределение)

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей, вычислительный-эксперимент

*Стрельбу по цели ведут до получения двух попаданий. Найти математическое ожидание
числа произведенных выстрелов, если вероятность попадания в цель при одном выстреле
равна 0,2.*

Я склоняюсь к тому, что ответом является:

```
M(X*Y) = M(X)*M(Y)
M(X*Y) = ((1-0.2)/0.2)^2 = 14,
```

но все равно есть сомнения: а может, *M(X+Y)* - правильно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Разве мат.ожидание не равно 10 просто по определению?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. У меня мысль идет в таком направлении, что эти 2 события - попадание в первый раз и попадание во второй - независимые (это могут быть 2 стрелка). В таком случае и величины тоже независимые. Тогда и нужно как раз M(X*Y)

Comment: Я могу ошибаться в терминологии, но если речь идёт о среднем числе произведённых выстрелов, то для одного попадания - это 1/0.2 = 5, по определению вероятности. До двух попаданий, т.к. события независимы, среднее число произведённых выстрелов(что я обычно и называю мат.ожиданием) - это 5+5=10

Comment: Вообще-то, просто 10. @vp_arth прав.

Comment: Я исхожу из формул, которые указаны в теор. материале практической. И там дана такая формула для геометричекого распределения: M(X)= (1-p)/p.

Comment: А при чем здесь геометрическое распределение? И потом, у @Harry кроме его теоретических выкладок есть подтверждающий эксперимент, а это, как говорится, и есть критерий истины :)

Answer (score 3):

Давайте прикинем - какова вероятность того, что надо стрелять n раз, чтоб попасть 2 раза? Это серия из n-1 выстрелов с промахами и одним попаданием, и последний выстрел - попадание. Вероятность получения конкретной серии из n-1 выстрела с единственным попаданием - 0.8^(n-2)*0.2, и вариантов размещения первого попадания среди n-1 выстрела - (n-1), так что имеем вероятность того, что надо стрелять n раз, чтоб попасть 2 раза - [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Для поиска матожидания надо умножить вероятность на n и просуммировать по всем n от 0 до бесконечности (реально - от 2 до бесконечности, но это ничего не меняет: первые члены нулевые):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или, так как p = 0.2, искомое матожидание равно 10.

Всё.

P.S. Ну мы же все программисты, нет? :) Проводим вычислительный эксперимент, в чем проблема...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

mt19937 gen(random_device{}());
uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0.0, 1.0);

int howmuch()
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int ok = 0; ok < 2; count++)
        if (dis(gen) < 0.2) ok++;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int total = 0, ok = 0;
    for(; total < 1000000;)
    {
        ok += howmuch();
        total++;
    }
    cout << double(ok)/total << "\r";
}
```

Результат [смотрим тут](https://ideone.com/9dXK4l).

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо всем, кто отвечал! Я таки написал преподавателю свой вопрос. Он подтвердил, что считать нужно, как я думал (вроде). Отдельная благодарность Harry. Он дал довольно подробный ответ с примером кода.
И, думаю, его ответ справедлив для множества случаев.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так все же, какой ответ (численный) назвал верным преподаватель? :) Потому что мне, например, непонятно, какое отношение ваши формулы имеют к поставленной задаче...

Comment: q/p - это мат.ожидание количества промахов. К нему нужно прибавить единицу - выстрел с попаданием. Также непонятно, почему вы решили, что вам нужно M(xy), а не M(x+y). Разве 2 испытания(x выстрелов и y выстрелов) порождают  x*y выстрелов?

Comment: В конце концов, можно же поменять p на единицу и повторить рассчёты. По вашим формулам выходит, что при p=1, M = 0 =)

Answer (score 0):

Если здравого смысла недостаточно, можно и формул накидать

```
X - число неудачных попыток до первого попадания
Y - число произведённых выстрелов до первого попадания = 1 + X
Z - число произведённых выстрелов до второго попадания

Пусть q = 1-p

P(X=0) = p
P(X=1) = pq
P(X=m) = pq^m

Ряд: p, pq, pqq, ..., p*q^m

Производящая функция:   
f(z) = p*sum((p*z)^m), m=[0, Inf)
f(z) = p/(1-qz)
f'(z) = pq/(1-qz)^2

M(X) = f'(1) = pq/(1-q)^2 = pq/p^2 = q/p
M(Y) = 1 + M(X) = (p+q)/p = (p+(1-p))/p = 1/p

M(X) = q/p = 4
M(Y) = 1/p = 5

M(Z=Y1+Y2) = M(Y1+Y2) = 2*M(Y) = 10
```